# Is there a way to use useInfinityQuery with Directus to enable infinite scrolling?

Tags: reactjs, frontend, directus, tanstackreact-query, react-infinite-scroll-component

I am somewhat new to Directus and React Query but after searching online it seems like it is the way to go.
I was wondering if anyone has seen or done examples of where they have implemented infinite scrolling on a Directus collection?

Any help would be appreciated! If anything, I would like some guidance on a working example and just modify accordingly.

FYI I am basically trying to implement infinite scrolling on a set of Cards. And I am trying not to use any third party software besides tanstack
Thank you so much!

I have tried examples from tanstack documentation and github. No one has done something as close as I am doing. I was wondering anyone has better advice.

Thank you!